# Cannot run Spring Boot aplication in Docker (Getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) in Windows 10?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, devops

I have a problem with my **Spring Boot Application** running in **Docker**.

Here is my **Dockerfile** embedded in my app shown below.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

After I run `mvn clean install`, I get an app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and then define it into a **Docker** file

Next, I ran this command `docker build -t app .` I saw this container installed on my **docker desktop**.

After running this command `docker image ls`, I also saw this container in the list.

I ran this command `docker run -p 9999:8080 app` to run it in docker.

The container worked flawlessly after running this command (`docker ps`)

Next, I test any URL like `http://localhost:9999/getCategoryById/1` instead of `http://localhost:8080/getCategoryById/1` in Postman but I get the message (Could not send request). When I test this URL in the browser, I get the message **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**.

I learned the container IP address via `docker inspect container_id` then I used `http://172.17.0.2:9999/getCategoryById/1` but nothing changed.

I also checked if the IP address manages the package (ping 172.17.0.2) but I got `Request timed out` message.

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootExceptionHandlingAspect)

How can I fix my issue?

Comment: Have you verified that your jar file runs correctly outside of docker? Once you are sure it does, you can look at the container's logs to see if there are any exceptions which would cause an empty response using `docker logs -f container_id` (-f to follow the logs in real-time). One of the causes could be that an environment variable is missing, for example. It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without having that jar file available, however.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I also added my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, `server.port` property in `application.properties` file, that's used to configure port for Spring Boot embedded Tomcat Server is `8082`.

To access the application on the container port `8080`, you'd need to override `server.port` property. One of the ways property can be overridden is using an environment variable like below,

```
docker run -e SERVER_PORT=8080 -p 9999:8080 app
```

where SERVER_PORT corresponds to the container port specified in `-p <hostPort>:<containerPort>`

Other option is to directly update the property in `application.properties` file like below. After the update, you can then use the same command you've used to run the docker image `docker run -p 9999:8080 app`

```
server.port= 8080
```